# Understanding purrr map output

Tags: r, purrr

Having a little trouble wrapping my head around what is returned by map

```
map(1:3, print)
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3
```

The first three outputs make sense, as they match what is returned from manually putting in

```
print(1)
print(2)
print(3)
```

Following this it seems to be some kind of nested list. Is there any way to get just one or the other?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I think what is going on is that `map` returns a list and `print` returns to the console. So what you're seeing  is the return of both `print` and `map`. It becomes really apparent when you assign this to a variable.

```
library(purrr)

#no assignment, both returns
map(1:3, ~print(.x))
#> [1] 1
#> [1] 2
#> [1] 3
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 3

x <- map(1:3, ~print(.x))
#> [1] 1
#> [1] 2
#> [1] 3


x
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 3
```

You can see here that even though you assigned `map(1:3, ~print(.x))` to a variable, `print` still returns 1:3 to the console and the variable x holds the values of 1:3 in a list.

Answer (score 3):

With `purrr` you can specify what output you want to get, like this:

```
map_int(1:3, print)

#[1] 1
#[1] 2
#[1] 3
#[1] 1 2 3
```

See `?map` to get all the possible outcomes. Of course it will throw an error if the outcome you want doesn't make sense, like `map_lgl(1:3, print)`, for example.

This is very useful when you use `map` inside of custom functions, because you can control the output, and catch an error if something goes wrong.

Of course you can use `map` alone, but like in your example, is better to use something more precise (`map_int`, `map_df`, `map_char`, ecc.).